# When I run this code it just says NaN or not a number. What could I do to fix this?

Tags: javascript

Also I'm really new to code, and this website. This is an area of a circle calculator. The equation for area of a circle is
3.14 * r * r.

```
    <input type="Number" id="index_radius">
    <br><button onclick="myfunction()">Calculate</button>
    <script>
        function myfunction() {
            var radius = document.getElementById("index_radius");
            var calculate = radius * radius * 3.14;
            console.log(calculate)
        }
```

Comment: Don't try to multiply an HTML element by a number? Maybe you want the *content* of that element, ideally explicitly converted to a number.

Comment: `radius.value` to get the value of the input as a string. `Number(radius.value)` to turn it into a number.

Comment: Or you can use `radius.valueAsNumber` to get the value as a number.

Comment: @VLAZ I find that `parseInt()` is usually faster - [jsbench](https://jsben.ch/pUy4Z)

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 1. `Number` was faster for me in Firefox and Chrome. 2. The difference is *negligable*. 3. Your suggestion is premature optimisation at its finest. Me writing this comment probably wasted *more* time than all of the code I've written combined would gain or lose from me swapping `Number` and `parseInt` calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `radius` variable is equal to the html element, not the actual value. To get the value as a number, you can addd `.valueAsNumber` the following code works.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var radius = document.getElementById("index_radius").valueAsNumber;
  var calculate = radius * radius * Math.PI;
  console.log(calculate)
}
```

```html
<input type="Number" id="index_radius">
<br><button onclick="myfunction()">Calculate</button>
```